# How to do SQL queries to sort rows based on keyword relatedness?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL table where each row contains two major fields:

```
          title                           tags
=========================        =========================
Best iOS apps you will...        iOS,app,apple,android...
```

Now I have a set of keywords on hand, let's say "credit,table,history,iOS,..." (up to 10 keywords)

And I want to search the database to see the best 10 rows depending on how the tags in each row are related to these keywords on hand.

I am wondering how to do this through SQL queries?

Comment: Read about normalization, refactor your database.

Comment: This would be easy if you stored your tags in a separate table with one row per title and tag.  It is very, very painful with your data structure.  You should fix the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your the direction you pointed out. So you mean there should be another table where each row has one title and one tag? If a title has 10 tags, then there should be 10 rows for this title? This table will grow very big if I have tens of thousands of titles, would it be a problem? any further advise? Thanks.

Comment: @joe . . . Exactly.  Databases are designed to handle large tables.  So, if you think that thousands or tens of thousands of rows are big, then you are off by two or three orders of magnitude -- and many MySQL databases readily handle billions of rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So if I have 50K article rows, then this tag table might have 500K rows (assume each article has 10 tags). Should I use another table in case of duplicate tags (tag_id/tag_string)? If I have this tag table, how to make SQL queries for the original keyword relatedness question?

Comment: You would probably have three tables, one for "articles" (or whatever), one for tags, and one for article-tag combinations.  If you have specific questions about how to use this structure, then ask as a question not in a comment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff should I create a new question or you can answer in this question because I feel they can be the same question except the table structure has to be changed.

Comment: @joe . . . This question doesn't explain the other queries you need to support.